# How To Reset JFrame (Restart Game)?

Tags: java, swing, restart

This is a java game that I have started working on.I have been trying to add a button that says "RESTART" which on clicking resets the whole program the way it was when it was at the beginning( i mean at the start of the game).

Here is my code:
There are 2 buttons namely "PLAY" & "CHECK WHO WON!"

For "PLAY" This is the code:

```
    int delay = 1000;
 final Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
  public void run(){
  String b = "C:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\Desktop\\deck\\.png";
Random r = new Random();
r1 = r.nextInt(upplim)+lolim;
String a = Integer.toString(r1);
String c = "C:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\Desktop\\deck\\"+a+".png";
        l1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(c));  
  }
  },delay, 50);
```

For "CHECK WHO WON!" This is the code:

```
final int p = h;
System.out.println("ANSWER IS:"+p);
        int delay2 = 1000;

     for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++)
{
    while(true)
    {
         next = rng.nextInt(Ulim) + Llim;
        if (!generated.contains(next))
        {
            generated.add(next);
            break;
        }     
    }
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) 
   {count++;
    deck1[e] = next;deck1count++;
    e++;
} 
   else {count++;
       deck2[f] = next;deck2count++;
    f++;
   }    
    System.out.println(""+next); 
        if(next==p)
        {break;}
}
 if(deck1count==deck2count)
{
count=count-2;
fcard=99;}  

 final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
         timer2.schedule(new TimerTask(){
 public void run(){  
do 
{
System.out.println("dec2       "+deck2[z]);
String a = Integer.toString(deck2[z]);
       String c = "C:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\Desktop\\deck\\"+a+".png";
       l3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(c));

System.out.println("dec1       "+deck1[z]);
String b = Integer.toString(deck1[z]);
       String d = "C:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\Desktop\\deck\\"+b+".png";
       l4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(d)); 

System.out.println("count"+count);
z++;
count=count-2;

if(fcard==99&&count<0)
{l3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\Desktop\\deck\\99.png"));
}
}while(count>0&&z==p);


if(count<0)
  {timer2.cancel();
  reschk=11;
timer2.purge();
  }
} 
  },delay2, 1000);
```

There is also another set of code which is written on the MouseClicked event of a label but I don't think it would be of much help here.
I have tried:

```
classname.this.dispose();
        classname classname = new classname();
```

But it just shuts the whole program down.Is there any other way to reset the game?
Thanks for reading.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post a good [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), and Please don't use new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\COMPUTER\\Desktop\\deck\\99.png") to access images. use a forward slash, this is Java or use this new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(...). It's always a good method to access Application Resources with java.net.URL

Answer (score 3):

You obviously have values which update so that you can represent your game during different states. If you want to restart your game, you simply need to set all of these values back to the original start values. You can write a Restart method to this.

Also, dispose() is designed to close the window.

edit: There is no magic method you can call to reset your program.

Answer (score 2):

1. For Swing based container use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) rather than `util.Timer`, otherwise output from `util.Timer` should be [out of EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).
2. You don't need to dispose old container and recreate a new for fresh game, you can remove its contents.
3. anything else isn't clear from code posted here, nor question

Answer (score 1):

Keep the state of the game in a distinct class and replace that with a fresh instance.

Comment: Run the game as a seperate class.  When you need a new game create a new instance.